# Why do some tags have 'tag badges' while others don't?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I've noticed that some tags such as **[meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)**, **[meaning-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context)**, **[prepositions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions)**, **[verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs)** etc., have tag badges. For example, StoneyB has both the ['Meaning' gold badge](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/198/meaning) and the ['Meaning-in-context' gold badge](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/191/meaning-in-context).

However, there are tags that don't have badges such as [phonology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology), [phonetics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics) or even **[vowels](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vowels)**!! (at least vowels should have tag badges).

What determines a tag to have tag badges (bronze, silver, gold)? What are the criteria for tag badges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well spotted! The difference between the tags is that some have 100 or more questions and others don't. Tag badges are only awarded for tags with at least 100 questions; see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

> Tag badges are only issued for tags that are being used on at least 100 questions.